# open a xib or addressbook from PSChildPaneSpecifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I know we can open a second view from PSChildPaneSpecifier in settings.bundle, i want to open a view(Xib) which is in my xcode project, how can i do this ?

or can i make a button in settings.bundle so we can fire view event ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my question so that others may seek help.
This is not possible with Apple Settings Bundle, so i decided to use this beautiful api [inappsettingskit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com). This works very Fine with plenty of other advantages and no cancellation of app from apple.

Regards